# how can I turn two statements into a ternary

Tags: javascript

I have two if statements that'd like to turn into a ternary but I don't know how.

```
if (val === true && optval === 'car' || val === true && optval === 'truck' )view_list.style.display = 'none';
if (val === true && optval === 'buss' || val === true && optval === 'van')view_list.style.display = '';
```

Comment: what should happen if `val !== true` or if `optval` is none of the values you showed?

Comment: There is no else statement, and your if statements seem better as if statements, not ternaries

Comment: @p.s.w.g I can only assume that nothing happens

Comment: Shouldn't be better to do `((val === true && (optval === 'car' || optval === 'truck'))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because nobody has said it yet, [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
if (val === true)
    switch (optval) {
        case 'car':
        case 'truck':
            view_list.style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case 'buss':
        case 'van':
            view_list.style.display = '';
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Apart in hacks I won't mention, a ternary is used when you want to return a value in all cases.

If `val` isn't `true`, then you do nothing.

Therefore this can't be used here.

Comment: I think this is the first time I've up-voted for *not* mentioning something.

Answer (score 2):

```
view_list.style.display = 
  (val === true && optval === 'car' || 
   val === true && optval === 'truck' ) ? 
     'none' : 
     ((val === true && optval === 'buss' || 
       val === true && optval === 'van') ? 
         '' : 
         view_list.style.display ) ;
```

or more succinctly :

```
view_list.style.display = 
  (val === true && ( optval === 'car' || optval === 'truck' ) ) ?
     'none' : 
     ((val === true && ( optval === 'buss' || optval === 'van' ) ? 
         '' : 
         view_list.style.display  );
```

The parentheses around the second conditional are optional.

Of course this is not really a good approach, and this answer should not be seen as an endorsement to this style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you were asking for, but as @dystroy said, this is not the best case for a ternary.

But you can still make it a bit more elegant. How about

```
var styleMapping = {
    'car': 'none',
    'truck': 'none',
    'buss': '',
    'van': ''
};

// Apparently val is always required in your example
if (val) {
    view_list.style.display = styleMapping[optval];
}
```

This also has the benefit that refactoring and adding new styles is very easy without having to write much code. Just add one line in the mapping and you're done. And of course it's much more readable and closer to what you intend to do.

You don't really care about boolean logic, you just want to have a different style based on what `optval` is set to.

Comment: +1 because this is easy-to-read and next year you'll still know what you wanted to do